# Cómo pasar parámetros desde JS para llenar un jquery DataTable?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

tengo un problema entre manos que no sé bien como encararlo. Explico el escenario.
Tengo una vista que ha de mostrar una lista de clientes en un DataTable de jquery. En esta vista existen tres desplegables cuyos valores se han de utilizar como filtro en la consulta y un botón para aplicar estos filtros.
Al entrar en la vista se ha de cargar toda la lista de clientes.
Si se selecciona algún filtro y se pulsa el botón "Mostrar" se han de aplicar dichos filtros al listado (no sé como hacer para pasar estos parámetros). Además se ha de poder utilizar la caja de filtro que viene en el DataTable sobre esos resultados filtrados en base a los desplegables.
El código de la vista es este:

```
    <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md mb-4">
        <label class="form-label">Cliente</label>
        <select id="filtro-cliente" name="filtro-cliente" class="custom-select"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md mb-4">
        <label class="form-label">Delegación</label>
        <select id="filtro-delegacion" name="filtro-delegacion" class="custom-select"/>
    </div>
    <label class="form-label">Activo</label>
        <select id="filtro-activo" name="filtro-activo" class="custom-select">
            <option>Si</option>
            <option>No</option>
        </select>
    <div class="col-md col-xl-2 mb-4">
        <label class="form-label d-none d-md-block">&nbsp;</label>
        <button type="button" class="btn">Mostrar</button>
    </div>
</div>

 <table id="cliente-list" class="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>IDcliente</th>
         <th>Nombre</th>
         <th>Delegacion</th>
         <th>Activo</th>
         <th>Contacto</th>
        </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

El código del controlador es este:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetListaClientes(int? IDcliente, int? IDdelegacion, bool? activo)
{
    var listacli = servicio.GetListaClientes(IDcliente, IDdelegacion, activo);

   return Json(listacli, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Y el código JS es este:

```
$(function () {
     //Estos métodos funcionan bien
      LlenarDLLclientes();
      LlenarDLLdelegaciones();

      //Este método es el que arreglar
      CargarClientes(null, null, null);
 });

 function CargarClientes(IDcliente, IDdelegacion, activo) {
    $('#cliente-list').DataTable({
     ajax: {
        url: "/Clientes/GetListaClientes",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json"
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: Solo te falta en el ajax añadir `"colums": [
                            { "data": "IDcliente" },{ "data": "Nombre" },....]`

Comment: Gracias Nicolas, pero lo que no sé es como pasar los parámetros desde el script del datatable a la consulta del controlador.

Comment: Hola Carlos, fijate en la documentación de jQ DataTables  en el apartado de "Server Side" explica los parámetros que envía la librería por defecto, son diferentes a los que tenés expresados en tu web-service, no recuerdo bien cuáles son, pero creo que eran algo como (int skip, int take, int order, bool sort) en cuanto lo encuentre, o si me fijo en algun proyecto anterior te lo respondo

Comment: también podés corroborar los parámetros que está enviando DataTables por medio de la consola del navegador en el apartado Network, te muestra todo el desarrollo de la consulta http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ésto es algo que puedo mostrarte de un proyecto anterior a modo de ejemplo

```
    [HttpGet("lista")]
    public object GetVentas(int draw, int start, int length)
    {

            var search = HttpContext.Request.Query["search[value]"][0];
            var order = HttpContext.Request.Query["order[0][column]"][0];
            var sentido = HttpContext.Request.Query["order[0][dir]"][0];
```

Pero podés investigar más profundamente en la documentación todos los parámetros que pueden llegar de parte del ajax de DataTables. Te paso otro link que encontré una explicación mas profunda..

[ENLACE](https://juancarlosganzo.me/2017/09/09/implementar-jquery-datatable-procesamiento-del-lado-del-servidor-con-asp-net-mvc/)